# debian GFS2 clustered file system dlm daemon missing

Tags: linux

I am configuring a GFS2 clustered file system on Debian 10, referring to https://manpages.debian.org/testing/gfs2-utils/gfs2.5.en.html. However, dlm daemon is missing, so I skipped dlm-related process. After configuring only corosync settings, doing mkfs.gfs2, and mounting, the following error appears.

```
dlm : no local IP address has been set 
dllm : cannot start dlm lowcomms -107
gfs2 : fsid=cluster:disk : dlm_new_lockspace error -107
mount /test : mount (2) system call failed: Transport endpoint is not connected.
```

dlm service is required in this configuration? Then how can I get dlm service? I can't find any package related dlm in debian 10.